# How to prevent runtime errors when working with angularjs and asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, testing

I'm working on a system that uses ASP.NET MVC and angularjs.

Sometimes, by mistake, the .cshtml files reference functions in angular controllers that don't exist, usually due to misspelling.

Here's an example. 
The second button uses function SetTxt, which should be SetText.

```
<button ng-click="SetText('account')">Click Here</button>

<button ng-click="SetTxt('account')">Click Here</button>

app.controller('MyController', '$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.SetText = function (text) {
      $scope.currentText = text;
   };
}
```

Is there an automated and lightweight way / tool to identify this kind of error in all html pages, before deploy and manual QA?

Thanks!

Comment: Unit testing by the developers, and proper internal QA prior to release.